# When new document is added to a different site it is added to a news feed

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way if another SharePoint site is update with a new document that there is a news feed shows up.  So basically when our HR team updates any new documents like health benefits that when they upload it to their site it gets update on the main NEWS FEED webpage? Keep in mind HR has their own site and most of the benefits or update is update through their DOCUMENT page.  TIA.

Comment: I assume this is in a "classic"-mode site?

Comment: Hi Willman this is on SharePoint O365, sorry I forgot to include that.

Comment: Yes, but even online, sites can be created in either "classic" or "modern" mode.  The Web Part named "News Feed" is strictly available in classic sites, so if you are using a Modern UI, then will need clarification on which webpart you are referring to?  There is a modern "News" webpart, but it only displays promoted New Pages, it does not display documents, there is also a "Site Activity" webpart, which is probably the most similar to the classic NewsFeed.

Comment: Willman - thank you for the quick lesson on the lower right hand corner it doesn't say RETURN TO CLASSIC, so I am on the newer version of SharePoint but one of the sites has RETURN TO CLASSIC and the other doesn't.  I will need both of these sites whenever a new document is posted to appear on my site.  Hope that helps and thank you again.